# Best practice for storing ID/decoded information in SQL table

Tags: mysql

I'm not a DBA by any means, but I'm looking at some databases that were set up probably 20 years ago to try to make sense of them. I'm seeing a lot of situations where they have two fields within a table that I think should be condensed down to one.

For example, let's say we have the following tables/fields:

```
TABLE = Employee
Employee.FirstName
Employee.LastName
Employee.EmpID

TABLE = Location
Location.StoreID
Location.StoreName
Location.City
Location.Country
Location.ZipCode

TABLE=EmpLocation
EmpLocation.EmpLocID
EmpLocation.EmpID
EmpLocation.StoreID
EmpLocation.EmpFirstName
EmpLocation.StoreName
```

It's these last two fields in EmpLocation that gets me tripped up. This seems like it breaks best practices for normalizing a database. If we ever needed to update the StoreName or an employee's name, we'd need to touch every record in EmpLocation as opposed to just a single record in Location or in Employee tables.

Am I correct in my thinking, or is this an acceptable practice? What are the advantages - besides minimizing joins - to storing the data in this way??

Comment: Still, I'd say this *was* a dba question

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: run a query and see if last two columns have value in them. It might be that they aren't used anymore, after adding 2nd & 3rd column.

Comment: You don't need those fields, nor is this one necessary: EmpLocation.EmpLocID, the employee id and store id can act as the primary key for the table.

Comment: Check the 2NF in db normalization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form